# Equivalent to R's sample(x,y,prob=) in Julia

Tags: julia

Julia-users: is there an equivalent to R's `sample(x,y,prob=)` to sample from a given set of values with weighted probabilities?  The `rand()` function is equivalent to `sample(x,y)`, but as far as I'm aware there's no option to add probability weights...  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

OK - done a bit more digging and `wsample` from the [`Distributions`](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl) package seems to be the answer:

```
using Distributions
wsample(population, weights, n)
```

Next time I'll look harder before posting!

Answer (score 1):

`wsample` exists also in the `StatsBase.jl` package (which I am not sure is a more recent addition compared to when the question was first answered)

If you go by `StatsBase.jl` you can also just use "sample":

```
using StatsBase
sample(population, Weights(weights), n)
```

In both packages you can also set a random number generator and whether to take with replacement for both functions too.